# wp-cli search is returning 'search' is not a registered subcommand of 'db'

Tags: database, search, wp-cli

I'm trying to search for a string like this:
wp db search some-string
and get: Error: 'search' is not a registered subcommand of 'db'. See 'wp help db'. wp help db lists 11 subcommands and search is not one of them.

How do I add or use the search subcommand?

I found docs on the global parameter to disable subcommands (disabled_commands: ) but there is no config file (such as wp-cli.local.yml) that would disable subcommands. I installed wp-cli and am the only user, so I should have a default install on OSX.

Comment: I think there is no `search` subcommand (only `search-replace`). Where have you read it? [Not the offical docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/)

Comment: here: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/ and here: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/search/

Comment: Make sure you‘re using the latest version of WP-CLI and update all packages as well.